# Recover after "accept" interruption

Tags: c, sockets, signals

Was writing program with server capability.
Here is short snippet demonstrating accept:

```
for (;;) {
        if ((c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, &b)) == -1) {
                if (EINTR == errno) {
                        syslog(LOG_INFO, "recovering after system call interruption");
                        continue;
                } else
                        err_exit(strerror(errno));
        }
        /* forking, client handling code */
}
```

Also I handle *HUP* by rereading configuration file so that signal could happen when `accept` is being blocked waiting for client requests.

Is the approach I use correct or there is another proper method for doing `accept` and handling signals?

**Does interruption by a signal flushes clients queue waiting to be serviced, that is my main concern regarding the question.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does interruption by a signal flushes clients queue

No, it doesn't.

> Is the approach I use correct

It *is* a common approach, yes.

> or there is another proper method for doing accept and handling signals?

Not answerable, as you do not show the related code, how you actually do the signal handling.